# Parent html form gets submitted instead of child pop-up form?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, forms

I have a jsp i.e customer.jsp  where i open the popup with below code snippet

```
  window.open('customerSuccess.jsp','customer', 'height=600,width=900,top=30,left=50,resizable=yes,menubar,scrollbars');
  document.forms[formName].action="../customer.do"
  document.forms[formName].target="customer";
```

This opens the CustomerSuccess.jsp which has function buttonClicked which gets called on click of one button.     CustomerSuccess.jsp has form with name Department

```
  function buttonClicked() {
    document.forms['Department'].file.value = '459';
    document.forms['Department'].submit();
  }
```

My question is parent window page gets submitted instead of popup window. I am not getting why it is not submitting the popup html form?

**What i tried:-** I also tried to get length of forms before submitting the form . Length come out out to be 1 and name is 
Department

```
var theForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");  
for(i=0; i<theForms.length; i++)  
    alert(theForms[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it with following code snippet before submission of form on child window

```
 document.forms['Department'].target="_self";
```

Looks like pop up window by default targets the parent window if we dont specify self for target